# HTML-PHP Table Colspan

Tags: php, html-table

I have a table and I want to fix the column so that it would be organized.

This is what I have tried:

```
print "<table table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"10\" width=\"100;\">"; 
print "<td>Date</td>";
print "<td>Payor</td>";
print "<td width=100><th colspan=\"3\">Songs</th></td>";
print "<td><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th><th>Album</th></td>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
print "<tr>";
print "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['Payor'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['Artist'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['Album'] . "</td>"; 
print "</tr>";
```

But the output is not what I expected.

current output:

```
|============|=========================================|
|    Date    |  Payor  |                               |
|============|=========================|               |
|            | Song                    |               |
|============|=========================================|
|            |  Title  |   Artist  | Album |           |
|============|=========|===========|=======|===========|
| 2014-01-01 | Customer| Mamma Mia |  Abba | Mamma Mia |
|============|=========|===========|=======|===========|
```

Should-be Output:

```
|============|=========|===============================|
|    Date    |  Payor  |            Song               |
|            |         |===========|=======|===========|
|            |         |  Title    | Artist|  Album    |
|============|=========|===========|=======|===========|
| 2014-01-01 | Customer| Mamma Mia |  Abba | Mamma Mia |
|============|=========|===========|=======|===========|
```

What should I add?

Comment: You should add `<tr>` instead of `td` in a table header

Comment: <tr width=100><th colspan="3">Songs</tr><tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th><th>Album</th></tr> should be the markup for the table header.

Comment: what do you expect as an output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make this beautiful!

**Update** - Seeing as you changed the code in your question... the following examples can easily be adapted for any output you need :) Just use this as a guide.

Why not have a pure HTML + CSS Fiddle example - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/ppC9r/1/)

**Edit** - Here is another example with rowspans - [Second Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/ppC9r/2/)

PHP and HTML

```
print "
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan=\"3\">Songs</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Album</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
print "<tr>
<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Artist'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Album'] . "</td>
</tr>";
}
print "
</tbody>
</table>
";
```

You should be styling the table with CSS... something like:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 300px; }
th,td { border: solid 1px #CCC; padding: 10px; }
```

Comment: how could i be able to get the desired output? Y_Y

Comment: Have you tried the PHP and HTML example in my answer? You should be able to replace what you have already with that block of code :)

Comment: wait ill try the 2nd link

Answer (score 0):

You still need to put the numbers for cellpadding and width in quotations. Like this:

```
print '<table border cellpadding="10" width="500">';
```

You also have errors in your table, in that you have `<td>`, which is a cell, around your `<th>` which is a header cell. You should have `<tr>` around the `<th>` instead.

The whole thing should look like this:

```
print '<table border cellpadding="10" width="500">'; 
print '<tr width="100"><th colspan="3">Songs</th></tr>';
print '<tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th><th>Album</th></tr>'; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
    print '<tr>';
        print '<td>' . $row['Title'] . '</td>';
        print '<td>' . $row['Artist'] . '</td>';
        print '<td>' . $row['Album'] . '</td>'; 
    print '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: If your code looks like what I have posted above then what is your problem? What does it look like and what should it look like?

Comment: @user3373430 did you also notice I corrected the code in your header?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and try this

```
print "<table border cellpadding=10 width=500>"; 
print "<tr><td width=100><th colspan=\"3\">Songs</th></td></tr>";
print "<tr><td><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th><th>Album</th></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's so

```
print "<tr width=100><th colspan=\"3\">Songs</th></tr>";
print "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th><th>Album</th></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write:

```
print '<table table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="100">'; 
print '<tr><th colspan="3">Songs</th></tr>';
print '<tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th><th>Album</th></tr>'; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
    print '<tr>';
        print '<td>' . $row['Title'] . '</td>';
        print '<td>' . $row['Artist'] . '</td>';
        print '<td>' . $row['Album'] . '</td>'; 
    print '</tr>';
....
}
print '</table>'
```

Answer (score 0):

From your tags i discover that there are lot of attributes with out the right values e.g like border there was no value and your tags were not properly closed. you can copy and past this code, run it and see how you table looks like now. i guess this helps you out.

```
<?php 
print '<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">';
print '<tr>';
print '<th colspan="3">songs</th>';
print '</tr>';
print '<tr>';
print ' <th>Title</th>';
print '<th>Artist</th>';
print '<th>Album</th>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 

 print '</tr>';
 print '<tr>';
 print '<td>'. $row['Title'] .'</td>';
 print '<td>' .$row['Artist']. '</td>';
 print '<td>'. $row['Album'] . '</td>';
 print '</tr>';
 }
 print '</table>';

?>
```